# error re-installing httpd on CentOS 7, how can I resolve it?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum

On a CentOS 7 server, I am encountering an error when trying to re-install httpd.  **How can I resolve this error and get httpd up and running again?**

Here is the first error that resulted when I tried to install httpd:

```
[root@server-ip-address conf]# yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.chkhosting.com
 * epel: mirror.nexcess.net
 * extras: ftpmirror.your.org
 * updates: mirror.team-cymru.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-18.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.4.6-18.el7.centos for package: httpd-2.4.6-18.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: httpd-2.4.6-18.el7.centos.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: httpd-tools = 2.4.6-18.el7.centos
       Installed: 1:httpd-tools-2.4.6-18.el7.centos.vm.1.x86_64 (@virtualmin)
           httpd-tools = 1:2.4.6-18.el7.centos.vm.1
       Available: httpd-tools-2.4.6-17.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (base)
           httpd-tools = 2.4.6-17.el7.centos.1
       Available: httpd-tools-2.4.6-18.el7.centos.x86_64 (updates)
           httpd-tools = 2.4.6-18.el7.centos
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So I followed the suggestion and tried adding `--skip-broken` as follows:

```
[root@server-ip-address conf]# yum install httpd --skip-broken
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.chkhosting.com
 * epel: mirror.nexcess.net
 * extras: ftpmirror.your.org
 * updates: centos.mbni.med.umich.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-18.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.4.6-18.el7.centos for package: httpd-2.4.6-18.el7.centos.x86_64
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    httpd-2.4.6-18.el7.centos.x86_64 from updates
```

I then tried to start the service and got the following error:

```
[root@server-ip-address conf]# systemctl start httpd.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit httpd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflicting version of `httpd-tools`, apparently from a source other than the official CentOS repositories. Remove it first:

```
 # rpm -e httpd-tools
```

If it gives you any static about it, add `--force` and/or `--nodeps` until it obeys.

When you then install `httpd`, it should also install a fresh copy of `httpd-tools`.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason a service is masked is to prevent accidental starting or enabling of the service.

For example firewalld can be masked with `systemctl mask firewalld`

When starting the firewalld service, you may get the error message

```
Failed to issue method call: Unit firewalld.service is masked.
```

To resolve this, unmask the firewall with `systemctl unmask firewalld`.